# Query.order on ndb.DateTimeProperty not returning results in the correct order

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have the following:

```
class Notification(ndb.Model):
    targetUser = ndb.KeyProperty()
    pointRoot = ndb.KeyProperty()
    followReason = ndb.StringProperty()
    notificationReason = ndb.StringProperty()
    sourceUser = ndb.KeyProperty() # User who caused notification to be raised
    raisedDate = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    cleared = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    clearedDate = ndb.DateTimeProperty(default=None)

@classmethod
def getActiveNotificationsForUser(cls, userKey):
    q = cls.query(ndb.AND(cls.targetUser == userKey, cls.cleared == False))
    q.order(-cls.raisedDate)     
    notifications = q.fetch(10)            
    return notifications
```

I thought this should work, as this doesn't use inequality filters, only equality filters.  When it didn't work, I added an index, defined in index.yaml as follows:

```
- kind: Notification
  properties:
  - name: targetUser
  - name: cleared
  - name: raisedDate
    direction: desc
```

However, getActiveNotificationsForUser is still returning the notifications out of order.
Does anyone know why or what I can do to fix this (short of getting all the Notifications and sorting in python)?

Thanks in advance,

- Aaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike with the old `db` library, `ndb.query` objects are immutable. So adding filters or sort orders to an existing query will always return the new one, leaving the old one unchanged. You should do this:

```
q = q.order(-cls.raisedDate)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I need this index?

Comment: If so, the dev server will create it for you when you visit the page where you're using the query. You rarely need to create indexes explicitly.